# creating Spring JPARepository method for entity variable with name "cId"

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entity class as

```
class Policy
{
private String customerId;

private String sicNumber;

private String cId;
/*
more variables can be ignored
*/
}
```

now inside JPA Repository interface, I want to create method that finds based on sicNumber And cId

following is the attempt i tried

```
Policy findBySicNumberAndCId(String policyNumber, String cId) ;
```

above method asks spring to search for "CId" property in entity class

likewise i tried almost all combinations

```
Policy findBySicNumberAndcId(String policyNumber, String cId) ;
```

above method caused spring to look for "AndcId".

now the question is what should be the method name that will target right property in entity class.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the way Spring Data JPA forms the query out of the method name. It follows the regular camel casing approach where the field names are inferred. As per the convention followed, if a method name has uppercase letters consecutively, the field name is inferred in uppercase.

So in your case, **findBySicNumberAndCId** - the field inferred is CId & is failing to find it.
One way to overcome the problem is having the method name with CId in the beginning with 'c' being in lowercase i.e., **findBycIdAndSicNumber** .

Alternatively, you can consider renaming the variable to avoid these issues or make use of @Query & define your queries if renaming the variables is not possible.

More info about the issue :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/1996